# Ca I create an APP-V FileNet IDM Desktop package?

Tags: appv

We have created an APP-V Package for FileNet IDM 4.0.3. The packaging process worked correctly but when I try to start the app the IDMObjects. Neighborhood. 4.0 can be found.

Any idea? Or does anyone has an manual to package the IDM desktop?

Answer (score 0):

We'll need a bit more information to get a solution for this. When you say the "Neighnorhood. 4.0" can be found, do you mean a particular file can't be found?

Sometimes applications have hardcoded paths and App-V does not always pick this up. I would recommend opening the package up in the Sequencer and checking the FileSystem tab for your missing file.